# in angular web application what needs to be unit tested?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, service

for a front-end developer, who writes angular code, what part of a javascript front-end project should I be unit testing? I find it needless to test a lot of the code, and my biggest hang up is which part of the angular services needs to be tested? if $httpBackend is a mock call, what's the point of calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your project grows in complexity, you may find that your angular application is doing a lot.  Angular's design allows the client to take a lot of the responsibility for processing and rendering data from the server.

Yes, I agree, you shouldn't test anything but your own code.  So, writing tests for `$http` is useless.  However, if you are expecting the server to return a specific JSON contract, and you want the assurance that you are mapping that correctly to a structure that you will use in your angular app, that is worth testing.  Further, if you are making calculations in services or controllers, that logic is worth testing.

Angular itself is set up to support TDD because it has a nice separation of concerns between the view, controller and services (even directives can be compiled and tested).  All of the javascript code that you write is a good candidate for test coverage. So, IMHO, you should be unit testing your directives, your controllers, and your services.  You can get as detailed as you want to give yourself the assurance that your code is solid.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, so pretty much anytime I write a code and I could use a mock for everything that's undetermined, the test will make sure the logic flow is correct. So that filling in blanks will yield the same results. Now two more question if you could please answer, I have extremely complex directives and by that i mean extremely complex directives, would the best approach be seperating the logic into seperate functions to test, or should I do a test for each of the functions in the directive? and 2, I often find my tests to be 3 x longer than the code itself, is that normal?

Comment: for question 1, I have a universal validation directive that pretty much validates length/pattern/value/ and many other aspects of these three and makes my life writing form validations easier and they perform complex validations, such as turning a credit card form's card type msg to 'please select a type of card first' when you try to enter a card number, etc. What's the best approach to writing unit test in this case?

Comment: These two questions could be new posts on SO.  I'm not sure I can answer them fully, but I'm sure some others could.  For q1: usually, I focus on one aspect of one function at a time.  So, you would have many tests that triangulate a function and exercise all its flows.  But as a general rule, try to only test one thing at a time.  For q2: It really depends on what you are testing.  But, I would say, usually tests are a bit longer, because they need setup and assertions.

Comment: As for the form validation, I'm not sure either.  Still finding my way with validation.  Perhaps e2e tests?  It depends how much your validation is dependent on the DOM.